# My company sells software to banks, is this riba?

Tags: riba, work, software

I recently started working for a software company that provides software and support to some banks and hospitals. Since I am not directly working with interest and not employed by the banks, would this still be considered riba?

Comment: I think your question is covered in my answer on http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/indirect-help-to-riba-business

Comment: It is important to note that most of your reference links are no longer working in that response and could compromise the overall accuracy of such an important answer which addresses many visitors concerns. Could this be rectified?