# Working at the company that has halal and harram business model, is it Permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, work

Let's say there is a company that generate revenue from finding an eligible or qualified person who can take a loan at interest(Riba). this company will get paid from the conventional bank if succeed to find a person who are qualified to take a loan.

And this company has some other business model that generate revenue. in this case they have 6 or more halal business model.

And the comparison between the riba and the halal in terms of the gain revenue is a secret because the company doesn't share about this. But let's assume the `haram` is around **5%** or more of the total income.

is it permissible to work on this company? or is it better to find another job?

And was there a case something like this at the time when 

the Prophet Muhammad صَلَّى اللّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم alive?

Comment: It is always better to find another Job if the Job has a taste of haram in it. And if you need the job it is allowed to work as long as you are not invovled directly in haram acts. One could even work at a bank as long as one isn't involved in riba himself. Also take a look at http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/indirect-help-to-riba-business

Comment: @Medi1Saif did the same cases happen like this one when the time Prophets Muhammad alive?