# What should i do with riba money if it is already mixed with non riba money?

Tags: riba

Assalamualaikum, I would like to ask what i should do with riba money that have been mixed with non riba money.

Let's say for example we do some business  and sometimes the transactions we do contains riba. Let's say we made $10 in one transaction. A part of that $10 contains riba(around 3%-10%). The problem from that $10 we don't know how many % of it is riba(the 3% - 10% are random in every transaction). $0.3 of it could contain riba or maybe up to $1 riba or maybe ocassionally a bit bigger than 10% of that $10.

Easiest example in real life is in the conventional forex market where traders got charged or earn from rollover fees(0-??%) if they have overnight transaction. The fees are riba, but what about the money that we made from trading?  is it also considered doing riba business?

What should we do if we are in this condition? How can we know how much riba money we should get rid of by giving it to charity? And are we allowed to continue this business even though a bit of it contains riba and even if all the riba money were given to charity?

Comment: You could view this as helping the bank by using their money with a portion of riba through the economy.  And then this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/is-indirect-help-to-a-riba-business-haram)

Comment: could you please explain further ? i'm afraid if i catch the wrong idea. so i am not directly dealing with riba business therefore my income is all halal?  or what?  Thankyou

Comment: Are you somehow "productive" in a riba business? Are you witnessing it or making contracts were it is clearly quoted? The hadith quoted in my answer which was linked @Tarik is the basis. Else notice that almost -if not- all of us would be part of a riba business as any money that passes by a riba bank could be suspected as being riba money and you may hardly find a cent in the world that doesn't go this way. As is written I'm confused about how to answer this. If you really had riba income (for example interest from a bank account) you may give it in charity but not for food.

Comment: no riba business, i just noticed that the interest fee they charge for overnight transaction is considered riba. and the fee is usually around 3 - 10%

Comment: easiest example might be on the conventional forex market, because they charge rollover fees for overnight transaction and the interest fee that we pay or earn is riba. The situation is a bit like that. Hope this helps describing my situation

Comment: Comments are not meant to last forever so consider adding any explanation or information to your post (use the **edit link**).