# If i work as a servant of a man whos income source is haram, is it haram to work?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I want to work as a servant of a man, who works at a bank. I know his income is not halal. So, if i works for that man, will my income be haram also?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For more details on our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your post I think the answer of [Is indirect help to a riba business haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/is-indirect-help-to-a-riba-business-haram) should cover your inquiry.