# Is being a Finance Controller/ CFO haram?

Tags: riba, money, halal-haram

In both of these jobs, the person has to decide how to finance his business operation which sometimes is by taking loan from financial institutions like banks. Also, In multinational companies, the person will be financing again through bank; here the probability of taking a bank loan is higher and one cant simply refuse to the Directors to not take the loan because they wont necessarily be Muslims.

Answer (score 2):

The matter is very simple:

Is dealing with riba part of your work? If yes it is haram. If not it isn't.

By part of your work I mean do you accept it or deal or negotiate about the interest etc. Or are a witness of this negotiation? See also [Is indirect help to a riba business haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/is-indirect-help-to-a-riba-business-haram)