# Is it haram to work for a company whose major shareholders are banks?

Tags: halal-haram, work

The company itself is a tech company and public. I found out that their largest shareholders are all banks. I am a software developer and consider the company to apply for this position. Is it haram to work for such a company?

Comment: This seems to me answered in [Is indirect help to a riba business haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/is-indirect-help-to-a-riba-business-haram)

Answer (score -1):

you work as a software developer, there is no wrong with that and your salary is halal.
but if you are uncomfortable with the fact your company might contribute to riba then you can opt out form that company.
as long youre not involved in the lending and borrowing of the money, youre good.