# Is working in bank IT department is haram?

Tags: riba, software, banking

I've been working in a bank for almost 1 year. I'm work involved in development & maintenance of remitting software and various bill collection utility (Electricity, Gas, Water etc) software. My job responsibility  doesn't require me to work in core banking system, which deal with usury/interest. But in future responsibilities might change as per managements decision. I may involved in core banking in future. What should I do now?

Comment: Yes, this is haram.

Comment: Your question should be covered in [indirect help for riba business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24453/13438).